# Select DISTINCT by name but different Address, Email from another table

Tags: mysql

--

I have the following MySQL query :

--

```
SELECT CONCAT(COALESCE(customer.last_name,''), ' ', COALESCE(customer.first_name,'')) 
as fullName, 
customer.first_name, customer.last_name, customer.email, 
address.phone, customer.customer_id 

FROM repairs

LEFT JOIN customer
ON customer.customer_id = repairs.customer_id

LEFT JOIN address
ON address.address_id = customer.address_id

WHERE CONCAT(COALESCE(customer.first_name,''), ' ', COALESCE(customer.last_name,'')) LIKE :search 
OR CONCAT(COALESCE(customer.last_name,''), ' ', COALESCE(customer.first_name,'')) LIKE :search 
OR customer.business_name LIKE :search OR customer.email LIKE :search OR address.phone LIKE :search

GROUP BY fullName

ORDER BY fullName ASC

LIMIT 15
```

Here's also some data :

(**customer** table)

---

```
customer_id | last_name | first_name   |    email           | address_id
1              Vandalay    Art            van@gmail.com           2
2              Vandalay    Art            van123y@yahoo.com       3
3              Dude        George         george79@gmail.com      4 
4              Christian   Forge          chrfrg@gmail.com        5
```

(**address** table)

---

```
address_id | address                 | phone
2            1st Art Institute, 23    +44392031
3            24 Oak Street, Berkl.    +62342354
4            51st Main, California    +662341232
```

(**repairs** table)

---

```
repair_id| customer_id |   other fields
   1             1         ...
   2             1         ...
   3             1         ...
   4             2         ...
   5             2         ...
   6             1         ...
   7             3         ...
   8             3         ...
   9             2         ...
```

The tables I'm using are **repairs**, **customer** and **address**.

I use CONCAT on **customer.last_name** and **customer.first_name** to generate the full name on which I'm searching, and COALESCE, because sometimes one of them is NULL.

If there happens to be 2 people with the **same first and last name**, but different **address and email**, my query will ONLY display one of them, because I Group ON the fullName, and will point me to **just** one of the two people (and to its **client_id**).

I need to get back with my query **DISTINCT** names, but when address / email  is different for 2 people with the same name, I need to have both people included (showing the 2 different addresses). So I guess no Group BY...but using DISTINCT.

Sample of DESIRED output :

```
1              Vandalay    Art            van@gmail.com         
2              Vandalay    Art            van123y@yahoo.com      
3              Dude        George         george79@gmail.com      
4              Christian   Forge          chrfrg@gmail.com
```

..so unique names, but I need duplicates if people "happen to have the same name, but actually are 2 different persons"

So far I get only one Art Vandalay, because I Group BY full name....

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove the GROUP BY clause. Performance benefits aside, if you want DISTINCT rows, select DISTINCT rows.

Comment: So my whole query was good, but using SELECT DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY it's faster and safer. In my mind DISTINCT should have selected unique values for each column (col1, col2, col3) while ACTUALLY after some research, DISTINCT (which I haven't used so much) is doing UNIQUE ROWS :)) thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Performance benefits aside, in general it's inappropriate to include a GROUP BY query absent of any aggregating functions. It's often leads to erroneous and/or unexpected (or, at best, indeterminate) results.

Comment: I know ! I was reading about that on the net the other day, and that made me come here and ask recommendations about how should I proceed. DISTINCT is definitely the choice on what I need here, and Group BY should be used when there are aggregate functions involved...